# How to set PHP variables in email TO header?

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to send an email using PHP mail(). I created a form that allows the user to input their information and press a submit button to send the email.

What I'm trying to do is to grab $email and set it to the $to header to send to the receiver. Everything else works perfectly, $name and $contact outputs just missing $email.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"><br/>
<input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Your Mobile"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
echo "Welcome: ". $_POST['name']. "<br />";
echo "Your Email is: ". $_POST["email"]. "<br />";
echo "Your Mobile No. is: ". $_POST["contact"];
?>

<?php

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];

$to = $email;
$subject = "Test Email";
$message = 'Hello '.$name.', contact: '.$contact.', this is a test email';
$headers = "From: Me <". strip_tags('test@mail.com') . ">\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

?>

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: `$name` is not set, and `$email = $_POST["email"]` will almost always pass. Check for `!empty()` instead, and assign the variables inside your if check.

Comment: The two things that jumped out at me: `$email` doesn't get set if you had provided a name because of the or's, and your headers aren't properly formatted

Comment: @aynber I set the name but $email still won't output unless I do $to="Arealemail@mail.com" which I don't want to do

Comment: @ChrisForrence I took out the or's since I didn't need them and my headers seem fine unless it's something I'm overlooking

Comment: You should be getting undefined index notices right off the bat here, on the first body of code.

Comment: Why the solution in the question? That should have been made an answer instead.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the first body of code I wasn't getting undefined index notices, just wasn't sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
<?php
if (!array_key_exists('Submitted',$_POST))
{
 ?>
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type="hidden" name="Submitted" value="true"><form action="#" 
 method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"><br/>
<input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Your Mobile"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
echo "Welcome: ". $_POST['name']. "<br />";
echo "Your Email is: ". $_POST["email"]. "<br />";
echo "Your Mobile No. is: ". $_POST["contact"];
?>

<?php
    }
else
{

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$contact = $_POST['contact'];


$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "Test Email";
$message = 'Hello '.$name.',<br /> contact #: '.$contact.', this is a test 
 email';
$headers = "From: Me <". strip_tags('test@mail.com') . ">\r\n";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

 if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
        echo "Message Sent";
    }
    else
    {
         echo "Message Not Sent";
    }
  }
 ?>
```